# "Invalid argument at position 1" error in Matlab and Simulink

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, simulink, reinforcement-learning, agent

I'm coding an RL environment using Matlab and simulink and I'm following the code set out in the following example from mathworks (https://uk.mathworks.com/help/reinforcement-learning/ug/create-simulink-environment-and-train-agent.html)

However for some reason when I'm defining my 'featureInputLayer' I keep getting an error stating that there is an invalid argument at position 1. I'm not certain on what this means, I've seen a few other questions asked here on similar topics but haven't been able to find an answer.

Here's the code where I'm getting an error (the featureInputLayer of StatePath):

```
statePath = [
    featureInputLayer(numObservations,'Normalization','none','Name','State')
    fullyConnectedLayer(50,'Name','CriticStateFC1')
    reluLayer('Name','CriticRelu1')
    fullyConnectedLayer(25,'Name','CriticStateFC2')];
actionPath = [
    featureInputLayer(numActions,'Normalization','none','Name','Action')
    fullyConnectedLayer(25,'Name','CriticActionFC1')];
commonPath = [
    additionLayer(2,'Name','add')
    reluLayer('Name','CriticCommonRelu')
    fullyConnectedLayer(1,'Name','CriticOutput')];
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: I am not a pro at this stuff, but it appears you are using an array here.  ANd I see that things are separated by semicolon.  I wonder if you switched the semicolons with commas would it work?

Comment: Can you post the full error text and the variable values?

Comment: Thanks so much both @DJBurb and Ander! I'll try and switch the semicolons with commas and here's the error text here:  
Error in Environment_actions_and_observations (line 31)
    featureInputLayer(numActions,'Normalization','none','Name','Action')


Really sorry I'm not sure what you mean by variable values. The 'Normalisation', 'name', 'state' don't really have numerical values as such. Apologies if I've misunderstood your question - I can post more of the code if that helps!

Comment: I think potentially I've found the issue? The first object in the featureInputLayer is numObservations which is then a function of actInfo which is defined as [0:1].

This might be the issue as the first object in actInfo is zero and therefore maybe not positive? I'm not really sure if this conclusion is correct however so feel free to chip in if you fancy, but instead of getting the previous error I'm getting other ones! 

thanks :)

Comment: Deary me! I should have been using a comma and not a semicolon in my act.Info definition!! 
Thank you all so much for your help (also I do believe that the first object has to be a non-zero number for the featureInputLayer - or at least for mine!).

Enjoy your days :D

Comment: So changing to commas worked?

Comment: Yes! It was an array earlier in the code that had a semicolon instead, the function I originally sent was a function of the array (if that makes sense). There was also 1 or 2 other things that came up afterwards but just general syntax and the like